# SQL Server - Find locations inside a geographic box

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, spatial

I have a list of 50 locations and their latitudes & longitudes in a sql server table.  I need to figure out how many of them are inside a box defined by 4 streets in New York City (42nd St, 57th st, 3rd Ave & 8th ave).  I've found the lat / long coordinates of each corner but can't figure out how to define the square and then filter for whether the 50 points fall inside the square.

Any suggestions?

```
-- 42nd & 3rd -      -73.97445  40.750767
-- 42nd & 8th -      -73.98979  40.757236
-- 57th & 8th -     -73.98288  40.766716
-- 57th & 3rd -     -73.96754  40.760254
```

Answer (score 0):

If "near enough is good enough" then simply checking the upper and lower bounds will work:

```
where latitude >= -73.98979 and latitude <= -73.96754
and longitude >= 40.750767 and longitude <= 40.766716
```

Otherwise, consider the various "point within polygon" determination methods described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon